# Windows Service in C# not starting up in a timely manner

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have searched and searched for Windows Service information and it is mostly non-existent or outdated. Further, there is no Windows Service template in VS 2013 (that I can find).

I am making a simple performance monitor that logs to a text file the CPU and RAM. I followed a couple outdated tutorials and came up with stuff on my own.

When I try running via F5 (a coworker's suggestion) the command prompt flashes open, closes and then the program ends. I don't think the OnStart method is ever invoked.

I can get the service installed fine from the VS command prompt but when trying to start the process I get an error that it does not start in a timely manner. I have even tried enabling interaction with the desktop in the Service Manager.

I have also tried both Debug and Release builds.

I have looked at other SO questions that suggested to do all initialization in the OnStart method, which I think I do (though I may be wrong -- I am obviously still learning).

The relevant code:

```
namespace SystemMonitorD
{
    public class SystemMonitorD : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer StateTimer { get; set; }
        private TimerCallback TimerDelegate { get; set; }
        private SystemMonitorL SysMon { get; set; }

        public SystemMonitorD()
        {
            ServiceName = "SystemMonitorD";
            CanStop = true;
            CanPauseAndContinue = true;
            AutoLog = true;
        }


        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            SysMon = new SystemMonitorL();
            TimerDelegate = SysMon.Log;
            StateTimer = new Timer(TimerDelegate, null, SysMon.WaitTime, SysMon.WaitTime);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            SysMon.StatusLog("Stop");
            StateTimer.Dispose();
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            SysMon.StatusLog("Pause");
            StateTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        protected override void OnContinue()
        {
            SysMon.StatusLog("Continue");
            StateTimer.Change(SysMon.WaitTime, SysMon.WaitTime);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
        }
    }

    public class SystemMonitorL
    {
        private readonly String _fileLocation = @"C:\Users\ian.elletson\Desktop\logD.txt";

        public int WaitTime { get; private set; }
        private IOutput Logger { get; set; }
        private List<SystemMonitor> SystemMonitors { get; set; }

        public SystemMonitorL()
        {
            WaitTime = 1000;
            Logger = new Logger(_fileLocation);
            SystemMonitors = new List<SystemMonitor>
            {
                SystemMonitorFactory.MakeSystemMonitor("CPU"),
                SystemMonitorFactory.MakeSystemMonitor("RAM")
            };
            Logger.WriteLine(string.Format("Polling every {0} second(s)", WaitTime / 1000));
        }

        public void Log(Object stateObject)
        {
            foreach (var monitor in SystemMonitors)
            {
                Logger.WriteLine(monitor.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void StatusLog(String status)
        {
            String message;
            switch (status)
            {
                case "Stop" :
                    message = "stopped";
                    break;
                case "Pause" :
                    message = "paused";
                    break;
                case "Continue":
                    message = "continued";
                    break;
                default:
                    message = "ERROR";
                    break;
            }
            Logger.WriteLine(string.Format("Logging {0} at {1}", message, TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(DateTime.Now)));
        }
    }

    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class SystemMonitorDInstaller : Installer
    {
        ServiceProcessInstaller ProcessInstaller { get; set; }
        ServiceInstaller ServiceInstaller { get; set; }

        public SystemMonitorDInstaller()
        {
            ProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            ServiceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

            ProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            ServiceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual;
            ServiceInstaller.ServiceName = "SystemMonitorD";

            Installers.Add(ServiceInstaller);
            Installers.Add(ProcessInstaller);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can determine whether or not the OnStart method is actually executing (say, with a log entry), try commenting out the lines of code in that method one at a time, to see which one is taking so long to execute.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I tried doing a Console.WriteLine in the file when running from VS but it did not execute. Should I write to the Windows Event Log for testing from the install-service workflow?

Comment: Console isn't going to do it.  Windows Services do not run in an [Interactive Windows Station](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096(v=vs.85).aspx), and therefore cannot directly interact with a user.

Comment: You can add `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` and it will drop you into VS on start (iirc). There is also some info from MSFT here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cktt23yw.aspx

Comment: You can force the service to launch a debugger by adding `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() ` in the start of the service.  From there you can start stepping through your methods to determine the cause of your problems.

Comment: I added an EventLog but can't find where it's writing to, however in Event Viewer I found that it said it's timing out at 30000ms on startup. I then tried Debugger.Launch() but that did not work either, unfortunately. I installed the service and tried to start it but nothing happened, I tried in both Debug and Release.

Comment: If you've never written a Windows Service before, you should probably start by [following this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) and getting a simple service working first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my problem. I was missing
`ServiceBase.Run(new SystemMonitorD());` in my Main() method. That solved the problem. I found this from [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cktt23yw.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

One thing that makes life easier dealing with while debugging windows services is to use the Debug\Release flag for your service. To step through the logic as a non-service.

```
static void Main()
{
#if (!DEBUG)
    //RELEASE FLAG  
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new MyService() };
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#else
    //DEBUG                
    MyService service = new MyService(); //<--Put breakpoint here before you run your service
    service.OnStart(null);    
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
#endif 
}
```